# Angular form validation using the controllerAs syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras, angularjs-forms

I am currently facing the following problem:

I would like to validate my form input using the Angular `ngModel` directives.

When using those together with $scope they work fine.
Now, working with the **controllerAs** syntax, they fail to work.

This problem is poorly documented, the only help I could find is [this article](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/07/01/using-angular-forms-with-controller-as-syntax.html).

Here is a small example of my code:

The template gets called with *myController as vm*

```
<form name="vm.signUpForm" ng-submit="vm.signup(vm.user)">

    <label for="name">Name</label>

      <input type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Full name"
                  ng-model="vm.user.name"
                  ng-minlength="2" required />

    <div ng-show="vm.signUpForm.$submitted || vm.signUpForm.name.$touched">
        <span ng-show="vm.signUpForm.name.$error.required">Please fill in your name</span>
        <span ng-show="vm.signUpForm.name.$error.minlength">A minimum of 2 [...]</span>
    </div>

[...]
</form>
```

Am I forced to use `$scope` to validate the form? Or did I miss something ?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Solution by:** Andrew Gray

I had to change the following lines to get this to work:

```
<form name="vm.signUpForm" ... >
<!-- To -->
<form name="signUpForm" ...>


<div ng-show="vm.signUpForm.$submitted || vm.signUpForm.name.$touched">
<!-- To -->
<div ng-if="signUpForm.name.$invalid">

<span ng-show="vm.signUpForm.name.$error.required" ... >
<!-- To -->
<span ng-show="signUpForm.name.$error.required" ... >
```

Comment: submitted is defined in controller?

Comment: It isn't, how should i define this ? Is this one of the properties that come with the scope variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first - you don't need the `vm.` on the form.

```
<form novalidate name="someForm">
    <label>
        Some Text:
        <span class="danger-text" ng-if="someForm.someText.$invalid">
           ERROR!
        </span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="someField" />
</form>
```

The way it winds up working, is that there's a validation object that is not tied to the scope.  The `controllerAs` syntax is just spinning off a instance of the controller as a scope variable.

Try shaving off the `vm.` from the form and child elements' names, and you should be OK.